# Why is my custom member resolver for enum to class conversion not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I get the exception message:

> The binary operator NotEqual is not defined for the types 'NotificationArea' and 'System.Object'

Source enum:

```
public enum NotificationArea
{
    One,
    Two,
    Three
}
```

Destination class:

```
public class EnumValue
{
    public EnumValue()
    {
    }

    public EnumValue(Enum tEnum)
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(tEnum);
        Name = GetEnumValue(tEnum, tEnum.GetType());
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string GetEnumValue(Enum tEnum, Type type)
    {
        MemberInfo member = type.GetMember(tEnum.ToString())[0];

        if (member.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>() != null)
        {
            DisplayAttribute attribute = member.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();
            return attribute.Name;
        }

        return tEnum.ToString();
    }
}
```

Conversion class:

```
public class EnumConverter : IMemberValueResolver<Notification,
     NotificationModel, NotificationArea, EnumValue>
{
    public EnumValue Resolve(Notification source, NotificationModel destination, 
        NotificationArea sourceMember, EnumValue destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var model = source.Area.ToDisplay();
        return model;
    }
}
```

ToDisplay Extension:

```
public static EnumValue ToDisplay(this Enum value)
{
    var display = new EnumValue(value);
    return display;
}
```

Implementation:

```
// Query
var notifications = await _db.Notifications
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp)
    .ProjectTo<NotificationModel>(_mapperConfig)
    .ToListAsync(token);

// Mapping
CreateMap<Notification, NotificationModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Area, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.Area));
```

Source and Destination Models:

```
public class Notification
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public NotificationArea Area { get; set; }
}

public class NotificationModel
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public EnumValue Area {get;set;}
}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong... obviously... I just don't know exactly where it's at. I feel Like I have A and C but am missing B.

Comment: Wow, what a lot of code!  I'm intrigued by your EnumValue class, you go through a lot of effort to do something (for example, you have a call to `MemberInfo.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>`, but you don't have `[Display]` anywhere in your code).  Have you looked at the System.Enum class - it does most of what that class does for free (well, from what I can tell).  You show the error message, but you don't say where it happens.  You have some text in between your code, but you never explain what you are trying to do.  Can you make it a little clearer as to your purpose for all this?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2723

Comment: @Flydog57 That is correct, not in this code sample. That just checks if a Display attribute exists or not.

This error is seen at run-time.

Sure. The end-goal is for the NotificationModel to be passed as JSON, the EnumValue will have the properties of the Enum but assignable to JavaScript variables.

LucianBargaoanu I just read through that and through the linked issues; I think my issue is different.